# Binary Tree Search Chech Algorithm Python Not Working

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I wrote this algorithm for a coding challenge on HackerRank to determine if a give binary tree is a BST. Yet in some cases when the tree is not a BST my algorithm returns `True` anyway. I couldn't find what was wrong, everything seems ok, right? Or is there something I don't know about BSTs?

Node is defined as:

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

My algorithm is

```py
def checkBST(root):
    if not root:
        return True
    else:
        if root.left and root.left.data >= root.data:
                return False
        if root.right and root.right.data <= root.data:
                return False
    return checkBST(root.left) and checkBST(root.right)
```

Answer (score 1):

A binary search tree has *all* the nodes on the left branch less than the parent node, and *all* the nodes on the right branch greater than the parent node.

So your code fails on a case like this:

```
      5
     / \
    4   7
   / \
  2   6
```

It's not a valid BST because if you searched for 6, you'd follow the right branch from the root, and subsequently fail to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at a picture below for which your code is giving an incorrect answer: [image]

Where are you going wrong:

**1.** if an element exists on the left subtree if there exists a node with a value greater than root.

**2.** if an element exists on the right subtree if there exists a node with a value smaller than root.

You should try this approach :

```
if not root:
    return True
else:
    if root.left and maximumOfSubtree(root.left) >= root.data:
            return False
    if root.right and minimumOfSubtree(root.right) <= root.data:
            return False
return checkBST(root.left) and checkBST(root.right)
```

Comment: The approach you suggest is quadratic in the height of the tree.

Comment: @PaulHankin Yes, but can be optimized if the author understands where he/she is going wrong...

Answer (score 0):

so the problem is to determine whether the given tree is a BST or not.
the best way to find out is through an inorder traversal.

- Do In-Order Traversal of the given tree and store the result in a temp array.
- Check if the temp array is sorted in ascending order, if it is, then the tree is BST.

this can be the approach

```
def check_binary_search_tree_(root):
    visited = []
    def traverse(node):     
        if node.left:   traverse(node.left)
        visited.append(node.data)
        if node.right:  traverse(node.right)
    traverse(root)

    fc = {}
    for i in visited:
        if i in fc:
           return False
        else:
            fc[i]=1

    m = sorted(visited)
    if visited==m:
        return True
    return False
```

refer to this for other methods https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/a-program-to-check-if-a-binary-tree-is-bst-or-not/
method 1 and method 2 are similar to your approach so it will help you to understand that too.